# Visual C++ Express How Exactly Do I Link A Third Party Library DLL

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010-express

YES, I have seen the posts that all you need to do is link it. Find you .lib and link.  I have 10 years IT experience and its not at all clear to me where/how the link settings are made. This is a DLL that is not in another project. I have the lib and I have spent hours just trying to find out how to pull this in.  Just curious, why there is not some tab saying external libraries, and a browse button to goto whereever you stored this on your file system?  I just don't get the multiple steps to get this file linked up.  Someone please spell it out. I'm on Visual C++ Express 2010.

Comment: If you're using VC++ 2010, why did you choose a tag for VC++ 2008?  I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just using "Add Existing File to Project", browsing to the .lib and adding it?  Visual Studio recognizes the file type and passes .lib files to the linker.

There's another way which is more complicated and also more powerful.  You can open the project properties by right-clicking the project in Solution Explorer.  Then go to the Project Directories and add the path to the LIB paths, then go to Linker Input and add the library name (without path) under additional inputs.  The advantage of this second method is that you can have different versions of the .lib and .dll for release vs debug, or 32-bit vs 64-bit builds.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bens answer, you can also use pragma directives:

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "path-to-library-file.lib" )
```

Some prefer linking libraries in the project, others prefer it in the source file. It doesn't make much of a difference either way.